# Collect properties of redundant keys and create new array with unique keys in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, higher-order-functions

I'm curious, what's the most efficient and modern way, to transform

```
const obj = [
  { desc: '1', name: 'a' },
  { desc: '1', name: 'b' },
  { desc: '2', name: 'c' },
  { desc: '3', name: 'd' },
  { desc: '3', name: 'e' }
];
```

into

```
goal = [
  { desc: '1', name: ['a', 'b']},
  { desc: '2', name: ['c']},
  { desc: '3', name: ['d', 'e']}
];
```

meaning filtering out duplicate keys and putting values of redundant keys into arrays of one specific key.

Comment: Use a `Map`. The algorithm itself is relatively trivial.

Comment: And some loops.

Comment: `const mergeDupes = (arr) => Object.entries(arr.reduce((acc, { desc: k, name: v }) => ((acc[k] = [...(acc[k] ?? []), v]), acc), {})).map(([desc, name]) => ({ desc, name }))`